# get content from external url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using freetexthost.com to store my json code..
and now i ve to get those content from url using javascript,jquery,ajax...
bt am being unable to get it..
am trying following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Useless</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
  type:     "GET",
  url:      "http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content" >Hello</div>

</body>
</html>
```

getting an error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

is there any chances we can manipulate content of other page(url) using js...

Comment: You have missed closing `"` in line `url:      "https://http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03,` Assuming it as typo

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < this error usually when json parser tries to parse html

Comment: Use your browsers network inspector, jsonp is not being returned. If you use the real url in a browser do you see raw json or json in an html page?

Comment: so how can i upload my json file in web freely so that i can use that later on easily??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: You're asking the question "You can I upload my JSON file", which makes me think the file that you are starting with contains a JSON object, but your script shows you using `dataType: "jsonp"`.  If your file contains JSON then you will want to use `dataType: "json"` instead.  But as others have pointed out, that URL seems to return an HTML page, and not a javascript or json document.

Answer (score 2):

1. in your json file create function:

   ```
    //----for example
    parseResponse({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
   ```
2. then call this function by **JSONP**

   ```
   var result = $.getScript("http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03?callback=parseResponse");
   ```

I hope to help you.

reference : [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your url using `"`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "https://http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03", // <-- Here
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure since he encountered a syntax error here.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the page http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03 is html, it should be jsonp to parse properly

The only difference between json and jsonp is that when calling jsonp you will also pass a callback parameter

```
e.g. url:"http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03?callback=myFunction",
```

Now the server side should print the json enclosed in this function name like below.

```
myFunction(
    {
        "sites":
        [
            {
                "siteName": "123",
                "domainName": "http://www.123.com",
                "description": "123"
            },
            {
                "siteName": "asd",
                "domainName": "http://www.asd.com",
                "description": "asd"
            },
            {
                "siteName": "zxc",
                "domainName": "http://www.zxc.com",
                "description": "zxc"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Comment: how can i upload my json file freely in web as jsonp and later on parse that easily??

Comment: You need to have a server side language like php to print the json text enclosed in the jsonp function name

Comment: You just need a normal hosting account